# Flutter : Could not determine the dependencies of task ':shared_preferences:compileDebugAidl'

Tags: flutter, dart

I create new app in flutter and it's work when I run it, but when I add shared_preferences package, I got this error when I run it

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':shared_preferences:compileDebugAidl'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':shared_preferences:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :shared_preferences_macos.
     Required by:
         project :shared_preferences
      > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :shared_preferences_macos:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
   > Could not resolve project :shared_preferences_web.
     Required by:
         project :shared_preferences
      > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :shared_preferences_web:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 866ms
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

this is my pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.3+1

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
```

What is wrong with that, and how I can solve it? help me please... thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue exists 
Use fix version like following as workaround, remove `^` 
shared_preferences: `0.5.3+1`

I have tested without error

full test code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: _incrementCounter,
          child: Text('Increment Counter'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ));
}

_incrementCounter() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  int counter = (prefs.getInt('counter') ?? 0) + 1;
  print('Pressed $counter times.');
  await prefs.setInt('counter', counter);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I was able to solve this problem by running the following command:

```
$ flutter pub cache repair
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a more widespread issue causing problems with multiple flutter dependencies. Until the Flutter folks fix the underlying problem, backtrack the version number of the problem module in `pubspec.yml` until the problem is resolved. It seems that modules that added MacOS support all fail.

For example, `url_launcher: 5.3.0` works.

NOTE: Don't forget to remove the `^` which lets it get a newer version than you specify.

Comment: You are a genius! Removing the ^ worked for me, this was the problem!!

Answer (score 1):

Flutter:(remove ^)
shared_preferences: ^0.5.3+1 -> shared_preferences: 0.5.3+1

android stuio: file->invalidate Cahces/restart

Answer (score 0):

I came across this solution from GitHub please try it and let me know if it works!
in PowerShell do the following commands:

```
setx PUB_HOSTED_URL "https://pub.flutter-io.cn"
setx FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL "https://storage.flutter-io.cn"
```

after that in your flutter terminal:

```
flutter pub cache repair
```